# Using IndexOf to search a combo box

Tags: c#, visual-studio, indexof

I've inserted a few `StaffRole` files into a combobox using the below;

```
for (int i=0; i < staffRoles.Count; i++)
        {
            user_Role_Combo.Items.Add(staffRoles[i]);
        }
```

I'm trying to search the index of a specific element within the combo box so it displays the correct element when loaded, I've got this, but it just returns -1 everytime;

```
StaffRole sr = new StaffRole("",roleID);
int comboBoxID = user_Role_Combo.Items.IndexOf(sr);
```

I'm doing this correct way no?!

Comment: Depends on whether this is WPF or WinForms

Comment: Please show your `StaffRole.Equals` method.

Comment: What's the type of `user_Role_Combo` ?

Comment: @SteveDanner It's WinForms, i think!

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I don't have one, I have an overriding method for toString(), is this wrong?

Comment: @Shai It's a Windows.Form.Combobox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for your new StaffRole instance to be 'found' in the combobox you need to describe why two StaffRole instances should be considered equivalent.

So you need to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`. Technically, you need only `Equals`, but these two methods need to be overriden together.

One way to deal with it is to base object equality on `roleId` equality, like this:

```
    public override int GetHashCode() {
        return roleId.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj) {
        if (obj == this) return true;
        var other = obj as StaffRole;
        if (other == null) return false;
        return roleId == other.roleId;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm doing this correct way no?!

No. By default IndexOf will check if the same reference exists in the items list. Since it's a new StaffRole that you just instanciated, it doesn't exist in the list.

I think what you want to do is compare by ID. To do this, you could override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` in the `StaffRole` class. In your custom `Equals` method, you would compare two objects by role ID. After doing this, `IndexOf` will work as you expect it to, by comparing using IDs instead of references.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use either

- FindString(String)
- FindStringExact(String)

Both methods will return the index of the element in the list that matches the value of the string parameter that the method receives.

Combobox [documentation here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't want to replace the equal / hashcode mehtods as I need them to be different for different instances.

So, I used some Linq to find the proper element inside the collection:

```
this.comboBox_group.SelectedIndex = 
   this.comboBox_group.Items.IndexOf
   (comboBox_group.Items.Cast<Group>().Where(x => x.Id == SelectedId).First());
```